# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found for Spring Security SAML2 Sample app

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, okta, okta-api

Getting this error when I try to configure the Spring Security SAML2 Sample app.

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Type Status Report
>
> Message The requested resource [/spring-security-saml2-sample] is not
> available
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
> for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/10.0.8

I can access Tomcat on this page fine - http://localhost:8080/, just cannot access the spring-security-saml2-sample page - http://localhost:8080/spring-security-saml2-sample

Following this guide:
https://developer.okta.com/code/java/spring_security_saml/
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html

pom.xml file details:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
            <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <!-- Tomcat embedded container-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml-dsl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.M3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Please can you share the rest of your code?

Comment: Sure, just updated it with the full pom.xml code that I am using.